# Boy born in space needing to somersault and spin to counteract earth's rotation

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, space, gravity

What is the title of the book I read in the 1960s or 1970s about a boy that somersaulted and spun throughout the day?

As he grew it became worse. The boy claimed he had a need to do this to feel right. His parents convinced him to "save it all up" till the end of the day and do it all at once in the privacy of their home.

In the end they discovered that the boy, being born in weightless space, was affected by earth's rotation / gravity (?), and that made him feel tangled up. I can't remember details and may have some of this incorrect. The book may have been targeted at young readers (teens).

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like *The Revolving Boy* by Gertrude Friedberg. A synopsis on Abebooks:

> From early childhood, Derv Nagy was marked out as being different. His uncanny sense of direction, his compulsion to turn and turn again until he felt somehow right, and the slight but definite slant at which he stood-all set him apart.

[image]